# C# get user from exchange in Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

i am devoluping an small add in for outlook. I need to access to the user that is configured in outlook. How can i access to that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this via the [Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.account_members.aspx) interface. See the following sample for details: [How to: Get Account Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462091.aspx)